# How to setup subversion on network ?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am trying to use Subversion (TortoiseSVN) as well trying to integrate with Visual Studio.
I have installed TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN on my machine.

I have go through the n number of articles but they explained in complicated manner or may be I am unable to understand it.

I have 5 team members and all of us working on the one project. (VS 2012) 
So I want to setup the subversion for us.

I just want to do the following stuff..

->  All of 5 can commit and can get latest version of any file of Solution, thats it. 
(Like check in and check out functionality of MS SourceSafe) 
I don't want use any other feature of it.

How can I setup the Subversion on network ?

Can anyone show me step by step procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pick a machine as the server which will host the repository.
2. On the server machine, install subversion
3. On the server machine, use svnadmin to create a new repository
4. On the server machine, use svnserve.
5. One each client machine, install subversion or tortoisesvn.
6. Each client can check out the files from the repository created at step 3

This hasn't even gone into creating the trunk/branches/tags directory, which you should do.  But that is pretty well documented.

At a high-level, svn://serverName/repositoryName/trunk should contain the VS project.  All the developers check it out.  Develop their changes.  Commit them.  Update to get everyone else's changes.

From a network-point of view, as long as the machines can see each other, that's all you need to do.  If the machines are all on the same intranet, using svnserve will be ample.  It can get more complicated by setting up http access into the repository, but you haven't said whether the developer's need http access.  So assuming svnserve is sufficient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Well all machines are in LAN. I would like to know more about the step 2 and 3. as well how to share the network path in repository ?

Comment: Don't know about SVNAdmin and svnserve , how to create that ?

Comment: svnadmin and svnserve are binaries that come with the standard installation of Subversion (not TortoiseSVN).  Look for installations of subversion (not client-only installations).  svnadmin provides administrative functionality on the repositories themselves.  You use this on the machine which hosts the repository.  svnserve is a server process which allows remote machines to access a repository (using the svn:// address format).  When using svnserver, you don't have to share network paths.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading this part of the doco: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.html